# Convert RDD[(String,List[String])] to Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My `RDD` is in below format. i.e RDD[(String,List[String])]

```
(abc,List(a,b))
(bcb,List(a,b))
```

I want to convert it to `Dataframe` Like below

```
col1 col2 col3
abc   a    b
bcb   a    b
```

what is the best approach do it in scala ?

Comment: and what have you tried ?

Comment: This is the second result from a google search "How to convert RDD to Dataframe." https://indatalabs.com/blog/data-engineering/convert-spark-rdd-to-dataframe-dataset

Update your question if you need help understanding anything specific.

Comment: Whatever this question may be, it is not opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first need to extract the elements of your `List` into a tuple, than you can use `toDF` on your `RDD` (spark implicit conversions need to be imported for this)

```
val rdd: RDD[(String, List[String])] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("abc",List("a","b")),
  ("bcb",List("a","b"))
))


val df = rdd
  .map{case (str,list) => (str,list(0),list(1))}
  .toDF("col1","col2","col3")

df.show()


+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
| abc|   a|   b|
| bcb|   a|   b|
+----+----+----+
```